# Add link url in autocomplete search

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I need to add URL to data returned in autocomplete search

My JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $( "#search" ).autocomplete({

    source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
            url: "{{url('autocomplete')}}",
            data: {
                    term : request.term
             },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                response($.map(data,function(obj){
                    //console.log(obj.city_name);
                    return obj.name;
        }));

        return(resp);
        }
});
        },
      minLength: 1
      });
});
```

My Controller

```php
$search = $request->get('term');

$result = Post::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'. $search. '%')->get();

return response()->json($result);
```

How can I implement url in results using id of Posts?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: based on your code I guess you are using jq autocomplete. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp this is the detailed example of how to use the multimple value in autocomplete